# To localhost from server deployment of Jenkins + Sonar

Tags: git, jenkins, sonarqube

I managed to launch a SonarQube analysis of a git repository from a jenkins job and this in an automated local way.
My jenkins is deployed on my port 8080 -> localhost: 8080
My Sonar is deployed on my port 9000 -> localhost: 9000

I now have to deploy it on a server where Jenkins is running but I do not know how to do it, I just managed to download the sonarQube plugin on the server Jenkins but about the rest, I do not know how to do it take.

Comment: How I'm supposed to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My jenkins is deployed on my port 8080 -> localhost: 8080 My Sonar is deployed on my port 9000 -> localhost: 9000... deploy it on a server where Jenkins is running

For production systems, consider installing SonarQube and a Jenkins build agent on separate systems. These services will content for resources at scale and increase build times.

---

#### Overview

It is helpful to understand the flow of information. These are the most common steps for triggering automated scans.

- User pushes code to Git services
- Git provider sends event (webhook) to build environment (Jenkins on :8080)
- The Jenkins server will schedule a configured job that executes the SonarQube Scanner Plugin on a Jenkins build agent. Note that some configurations may have a build agent on the same machine as the server.
- When the scanner completes, it will send results to the SonarQube server (:9000) that is configured in Jenkins

#### Configuration

> managed to download the sonarQube plugin on the server Jenkins

The main configuration will happen in the [Jenkins **Global Tool Configuration**](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzingwiththeSonarQubeScanner). Follow the instructions on this page to configure SonarQube Scanner and creating a job.

**Simplified Steps**

1. **Configure Jenkins to point to your SonarQube server**

   Scroll down to the **SonarQube Scanner** configuration section and click on **Add SonarQube Scanner**. It is based on the typical Jenkins tool auto-installation. You can either choose to point to an already installed version of SonarQube Scanner (uncheck 'Install automatically') or tell Jenkins to grab the installer from a remote location (check 'Install automatically'):
2. **Add the SonarQube Scanner build step to your build**